# Decode rf remote signals with ESP32 or node MCU?

Tags: nodemcu, esp32, wireless, rf, signal-processing

I'm trying to decide my rf remote signals using ESP32 or node MCU. I have tried with Arduino and was successful but for some reason it is not working on either ESP32 or node MCU even using the same GPIO2 pin can anyone please tell me why both the boards are not able to decode the signal. I'm using the rc-switch library to decode and a 433Mhz transmitter reciever combo from amazon

````
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySwitch.enableReceive(0);  // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2
}

void loop() {
  if (mySwitch.available()) {
    output(mySwitch.getReceivedValue(), mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength(), mySwitch.getReceivedDelay(), mySwitch.getReceivedRawdata(),mySwitch.getReceivedProtocol());
    mySwitch.resetAvailable();
  }
}```
````

Comment: Please include the wiring and your code into the question. You can edit it to add these information.

Comment: Maybe it's related with 3.3V/5V difference?

Comment: @chrisl I have also put up the code

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I used the vin pin on both the boards which provide 5v and the reciever also works on 5v so I don't this that's the case and also I used the 5v pin on Arduino just to be sure

Comment: io 0 has a pull-up resistor because it is a boot config pin and on esp the interrupt pin numbers are the same as the labels on ocb

Comment: I thought ESP32 was 3.3V (but it was just an idea it might be caused by voltage difference).

Answer (score 1):

For ESP32, you should provide real GPIO number.
For instance:
mySwitch.enableReceive(13);

And without deep explanation, believe that it properly works
with GPIO 13 and 27.
Details you can find by google...